# How to get, in my custom Layout (VBox,HBox, etc) element, all the childrens tag writed in fxml

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

I'm trying to create my own custom componets in JavaFx and use it in FXML file, but i can get, inside my custom component, all the childrens tag (nested components) writed in the fxml file.

For example:

I have my custom components (class): "Form" this extends from VBox, and i have a fxml file where i implements my custom components. So, i need to get in my "Form" object all the "TextField" children, and manage them items.

Form.java

```
package ui.control;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
public class Form extends VBox {
  public Form (){
      System.out.println(getChildren().size());
  }
}
```

In this case, i just need to show the total of TextField's inside the Form.

Test.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import ui.control.Form?>

<VBox 
  prefHeight="400.0" 
  prefWidth="600.0" 
  spacing="10.0" 
  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" 
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
  <padding>
     <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
  </padding>
  <children>      
     <Form fx:id="User_Form">
        <TextField promptText="First Name"/>
        <TextField promptText="Last Name"/>
        <TextField promptText="Email"/>
     </Form>      
  </children>
</VBox>
```

I also try the fxml file in this way (using children tags) and have the same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import ui.control.Form?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
   <children>
      <Form fx:id="User_Form">
         <children>
            <TextField promptText="First Name"/>
            <TextField promptText="Last Name"/>
            <TextField promptText="Email"/>
         </children>
      </Form>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

So, when i run my code, this is my output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMMZ9.png)

And there is my UI:
[UI_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67JIG.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the *"manage them items"* part. At the time the constructor completes, the children have not been added to the `Form`. You could of course register a listener to the list that executes on updates, but this is a rather inelegant solution. There may be a better solution though, but choosing a suitable solution would require knowlege about the intended use of the `Form`.

Comment: Ok, you can send me a example of your solution? how I can register a listener to the list? I need this Form component to validate all the inputs inside before the user complete the form. And this kind of solution will help me to create another components with nested children's

Comment: There's an example of a `ListChangeListener` [in the javadocs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html). You'll need to adjust it to use the correct type and probably you're not interested in permutations/updates... Note that there should be 3 changes triggered for the fxml in your question.